# Who is Clorthax?

Tags: steam

"Clorthax" is the guy prominently featured in the Steam Summer Sale 2022, and is introduced as "*a time-travelling trickster*".
You might have seen him:

| [image: Clorthax portrait] | [image: Clorthax portrait] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |

<sup>*This guy!*</sup>

I get Clorthax is not a real person (although mentioned on Steam — and thus on Google — as being the developer and publisher for all of "the ten best games from the far future"):

[image: result in Google Knowledge Panel after searching for "Clorthax"]

Anyhow, I want to know who the guy in the picture is (and why he was chosen to represent this person from the future).

Answer (score -2):

He looks like David Tennant.... about the time-traveler, I can say that he was in Doctor Who, acted as the 10th doctor (from here they took 10 games). And but honestly how to explain that he is a trickster, I don't know... Maybe because he sometimes deceived the story in the series, who know. Glitch-effects can be easily confused, but this version is my headcanon.

Comment: Maybe the trickster part is because of the Tardis, which is definitely not what it looks like

Comment: He looks nothing like David Tennant